# Continuity and Density

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

If a function is continuous on an interval $(a,b)$, does it mean that it is dense in the interval $[f(a), f(b)]$? Can I use the continuity of $\sin x$ to show that it is dense in $[0,1]$?

Comment: What do you mean "it's dense"? Do you mean its image, or do you mean the function itself, because a function is not a subset of $\Bbb R$, whereas a dense set is a subset of $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you mean to say does the image of $f$, meaning the set $\{f(x)| x\in[a,b]\}$ contain all points in the set $[f(a),f(b)]$. In that case, the answer is yes. See [the intermediate value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem).

It can, however, contain even more than just $[f(a),f(b)]$. See for example $f(x)=x^2$ on $[-1,1]$.